# Firebase realtime database - add data to existing node

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to append data to the node that already exists. As you see at the image below.

[image: database]

I was trying to use set or update but i couldnt get the right result with both of them. I tried to use push but i don't want to add unique id database provides.

This is what my code looks like right now. It's working but I believe there is a better way to do it.

```
  Future<bool> addUserToRoom(String roomCode) async {
    try {
      User? user = firebaseAuth.currentUser;
      DatabaseReference ref = rtdb.ref();

      DataSnapshot snapshot = await ref.child("rooms/$roomCode/users").get();
      if (snapshot.exists) {
        List<Object?> users = snapshot.value as List<Object?>;
        users = users.toList();
        users.add(user!.uid);
        await ref.child("rooms/$roomCode/users/").set(users);
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      Get.snackbar("Error while creating account", e.toString());
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the order of the users matters, a better approach is to use a map-like data structure, where the UID is the key and you store `true` as the value. In code that'd be something like this:

```
ref.child("rooms/$roomCode/users").child(user!.uid).set(true);
```

Advantages of this:

- Writing the UID is now idempotent, which means you no longer need to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) to modify the `users` node atomically.
- A UID can by definition only appear once in the `users` node this way, even of you make a coding mistake.

If on the other hand you need to have an order to the users, and want to allow duplicates, you should use [Firebase's built-in `push()` operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data), rather than using a `List`/array. For more on why that is, read [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).